# A boundedness of identity operator

Tags: operator-theory

Suppose $I\colon L_p(0,1)\to L_q(0,1),\,1\leq p < q <\infty$. I claim that this operator even is not defined over all $L_p(0,1)$. Therefore, we cannot speak about its boundedness. Am I right?

Comment: There exists such a function $f\in L_p(0,1)\setminus L_q(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the concept of operator with which you operate. :) If an operator is required to be defined on the entire space $L_p$ then yes, the identity isn't an operator at all.

But  it is also common to consider *densely defined* operators, which may or may not be bounded. The domain of such an operator acting on $L^p$ is a dense linear subspace of $L^p$, e.g., $C^\infty$ smooth functions, or polynomials.

In this sense, we can say that the identity $I:L_p(0,1)\to L_q(0,1)$ is a densely defined operator which is unbounded when $p<q$.